# Excel Automation Error# 1004 Method '~' of object '~' failed

Tags: excel, vba, vb6, automation, add-in

Using VB6 to do some Excel automation I have this code which has worked well for the past 5+ years. It basically iterates through the Add-Ins and if it detects a certain one then it issues a message to the user.

```
        Public xlapp As Excel.Application
        Set xlapp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

        Dim CurrAddin As Office.COMAddIn

        For Each CurrAddin In xlApp.COMAddIns
2           LogMe "==>COM Add-In: " & CurrAddin.Description

            'detect the PowerPivot add-in
3           If CurrAddin.Description = "PowerPivot for Excel" And CurrAddin.progID = "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Modeler.FieldList" Then
4               LogMe "==>COM Add-In 'PowerPivot for Excel is set to load=" & CurrAddin.Connect

5               If CurrAddin.Connect = True Then
6                   MsgBox "The PowerPivot Add-in for Excel is installed and set to load.", vbExclamation
                End If
            End If
9       Next CurrAddin

Error in MyAddInEnumerator
1004
Method '~' of object '~' failed
Line: 2
```

After putting an error catcher on this routine the debug says it happens on Line 2. Interactive debugging shows this is really in the line above. CurrAddin seems to have already been initialized so the issue is with xlApp.COMAddIns.

I have this app running on many machines with the same version of 32-bit Excel 2010. These machines run Win7x86 and Win7x64 and all but one run fine with no errors. I just cant figure out why this one machine bombs on using the object "COMAddIns".

Comment: The references are in a VB6 application which is then compiled to an EXE. Everyone runs the app from the server and are thus touching the same thing. Unless you mean something else.

Comment: I see. Check this out, maybe it helps: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/178510

Comment: Yeah saw that article plus about 10 others. That doesn't explain why it works on 15 other machines that have the same version of Excel. Plus I am setting the xlapp variable only once as a global variable and all the variables seem to be fully qualified. But let me scour my code again.

Comment: Yeah. Are you sure that the machines are the "same"? Meaning are they the clones of each other? If not, there may be some other service packs etc. installed on the one that is misbehaving. One more article may be of help: http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/996711-post4.html

Comment: Office is controlled by the IT admin but I did check and our versions are the same as in Version: 14.0.7166.5500 (32-bit). The add-in enumerator is a small routine as above and if I put an error catcher within this routine it displays the error but once past it all other automation with Excel works as usual.

Comment: Is there any COMAddIn present actually? On that machine? Or you are trying to call the Description of a null object? Maybe that specific COMAddIn does not have a Description property. Can you test it from Excel VBA on that machine?

Comment: It fails on calling COMAddIns. It never gets to the description. If I add one line before the loop xlApp.COMAddIns.Update it will fail there. COMAddIns for some reason fails on this machine.

Comment: have you resolved this issue?

Comment: This was several years ago. I'm not sure but I think the user is no longer in our group.

Answer (score 0):

Try to test the object before accessing it:

```
For Each CurrAddin In xlApp.COMAddIns
    'Add this line below and the End If
    If Not IsNull(CurrAddin) Then
        LogMe "==>COM Add-In: " & CurrAddin.Description

        'detect the PowerPivot add-in
        If CurrAddin.Description = "PowerPivot for Excel" And CurrAddin.progID = "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Modeler.FieldList" Then
            LogMe "==>COM Add-In 'PowerPivot for Excel is set to load=" & CurrAddin.Connect

            If CurrAddin.Connect = True Then
                MsgBox "The PowerPivot Add-in for Excel is installed and set to load.", vbExclamation
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next CurrAddin
```

A null reference or undeclared object is a likely cause of 1004 errors, as in some other SO articles:

[VBA Excel: Run-time error '1004' Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' faile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30333414/vba-excel-run-time-error-1004-method-range-of-object-worksheet-faile?rq=1)

[Broken Excel VBA Macro Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25370674/broken-excel-vba-macro-run-time-error-1004-method-range-of-object-global?rq=1)

[Error '1004' Method 'Range' of object'_Global failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23322408/error-1004-method-range-of-object-global-failed?rq=1)

HTH. This would likely still detect of you *do* have the add-in. Otherwise it is probably a re-install issue as here: http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/996711-post4.html.

Comment: Same as above. It's not the description that's failing it's the call to xlApp.COMAddIns. it's baffling.

Comment: OK. I clean up the comments above now. I'd try to reinstall. Obviously some library is off, I don't have any more idea to trace it down and this is the best suggestion regarding this error code on the web, other than testing for a null object. You could test the `CurrAddin` for null: `If Not IsNull(CurrAddin) Then`  This would make your test probably still valid as you are looking for a specific one.

Comment: If I get rid of the loop and make just one statement xlApp.COMAddIns.Update it fails there. Somehow COMAddIns is not available on that one machine. I may have him repair the install.

Comment: Yes, but you can go into the loop and then test for null: `If Not IsNull(CurrAddin) Then` I would test this if is detects your add-in. If yes, that is a feasible workaround. Otherwise yes, reinstall.

Comment: No you cannot. When it fails on xlApp.COMAddIns it will never get to the inside of the loop. It fails on the line before line #2. In your example it fails in the very first line.

Comment: OK. Well. I would not waste more time on trying to trace it down, it is likely an installation issue. That's your best bet. I voted your question up though as it is a valuable issue and now well documented here.